# How to remove unknown characters from a string which follows a particular format?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a String in this format: `&?0907141|somename|5009-07-2014|sample`

All I want to do is to remove 50 from the above String format, but the number might be anything not just 50, I cannot go by index position since the text "somename" might be changed to something else, but String will always be in the same format as above. 
How do I remove it in the easiest possible way?

Comment: is it always 2 digits though?

Comment: Check each char after a "|", if int remove the next two digits. If it's more/less than two digits then you should format it better

Comment: Check out http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_grouping

Comment: @scary Yea it is always 2 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove two characters after the second pipe.

```
String s = "&?0907141|somename|5009-07-2014|sample";
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("(.*\\|.*\\|)..(.*\\|.*)", "$1$2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String.replaceAll ("\\|[0-9]{2}", "|");
```

it will replace a pipe and 2 digits with a pipe

Comment: I got this error Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: You need two backslashes (one for the regex, and another one because it needs to be escaped).

Answer (score 0):

```
1. String[] arr= `String#split()` on `|`
2. use replace() / regex etc on  arr[2].
3. Code..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "&?0907141|somename|5009-07-2014|sample";
String splits[] = s.split("\\|");

s = splits[0] + "|" + splits[1] + "|" + splits[2].substring(2) + "|" + splits[3];
```

Comment: This is much easier But I got a StringOutOfBound exception

Comment: `String.split()` takes a regular expression, so you'd need to do `s.split("\\|")`.